# customizing shortcut keys in foxit reader for linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, foxit-reader

I use foxit reader version `FoxitReader.enu.setup.2.4.4.0911.x64.run` in linux (peppermint os 10). I searched for customizing shortcut keys, and got the answer is  "No" from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33530275/6851693), but this answer is old (from 2015). And with the new version of foxit reader I used, go to `Help` -> `Keyboard mapping`, and got this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZapK.png)

but I don't know how to customize with this, I click in a `action-keyboard`, but nothing happens. Since the option `Keyboard mapping` shows a table with **many actions still are not assigned shortcut keys**, I guest that it not just a table of shorcut keys, and we may customize shortcut keys in this version of foxit reader. Could you confirm that?

Answer (score 0):

I have an ugly but effective solution. I use the "typewriter" feature of Foxit reader frequently when annotating PDFs. The workaround for me was simply to write a tiny script that uses **xdotool** to send key commands which navigate through Foxit Reader's menus e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep .1
xdotool key alt
xdotool key Right
xdotool key Right
xdotool key Right
xdotool key Right
xdotool key Down
xdotool key Down
xdotool key Down
xdotool key Down
xdotool key Down
xdotool key Down
xdotool key Down
xdotool key Down
xdotool key Return
```

I've bound this script to a keyboard shortcut in my window manager. Ugly? Yes. But it only took two minutes and it works reliably.

Answer (score -1):

I feel your pain as I have been been trying to find out the same. The short answer is that we have to use Wine + FoxIt Windows installer.

The long answer is:

Unfortunately in the official [User Manuals](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/support/usermanuals.php), we find the latest [Manual for Mac & Linux](https://help.foxitsoftware.com/manuals/pdf-reader/foxit-reader-for-mac/en-us/3.4.0/). Under the [Keyboard shortcuts](https://help.foxitsoftware.com/manuals/pdf-reader/foxit-reader-for-mac/en-us/3.4.0/Keyboard_Shortcuts.html) section, there is no mention of the `Single-Key Accelerators` that is present in the [Windows Manual](http://cdn01.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/manual/reader/en_us/FoxitReader9.7_Manual.pdf). This is the missing function that allows keyboard shortcut customization.